# How Can A .dll File Read a .txt File?

Tags: c++, dll, text, bho

I would like my Browser Helper Object which is simply a .dll, to be able to read a text file. I have tried using a pointer to a FILE, as well as ifstream in("file name goes here"). Before implementing these two methods of reading files into the BHO, I tested them individually, and made sure each example dealt with similar data types and locations. Both of them worked without a problem, yet testing the BHO reveals that the file cant even be opened. I have searched google for an alternative method, and after exhausting all other options, I'm hoping that someone would be able to provide me with some guidance/resource. Anything is appreciated; I will keep trying to find a solution and will post what I can in the event that someone else may have the same problem.

Comment: FYI, this question is tagged with `C` language, but talks about the `C++ ifstream`.

Comment: I know! files don't read each other. Was that the answer? Is this like those "what did the spoon say to the knife" jokes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you providing an absolute path to the file?  If you're just using a relative path you may not be in the same working directory while running IE.

Comment: thank you, I realized I had to use the absolute path name to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be a victim of the IE protected mode.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/PMSurvivalGuide.aspx

Under protected mode your addin might not have access to registry and file system as you might like.